# Java Code to create XML file from XSD without any POJO

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I just want to create XML file by only using XSD without using any POJO. I tried to search solutions, but most of them using JAXB those are dependent on Classes and Marshaling. I feel like to create an XML file with XSD we don't require any other dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I got the simplest solution for this problem using jlib.

https://github.com/elbuo8/Sample-XSD-to-XML-Batch-Generator/blob/master/Runner.java